# Upgrade Status stuck at Waiting To Upgrade (2010 to 2013)

Tags: 2013, upgrade

I have a SharePoint 2013 farm which has 2010 customizations deployed and 2010 content databases attached and mounted. The site collection now works great in 2010 mode and the site collection health checks for conversion to 2013 mode have passed without errors.

Using the browser, I've asked that the site collection be converted to 2013 mode, however once it gets to the "Waiting To Upgrade" status, the site collection remains in that state. I have the browser set to "automatically refresh every minute" and there is no change in the status after 4 hours. This is the only site collection upgrade that has been requested.

Is there some missing configuration? Is there a way to find out why it's stuck at this point?

[image]

EDIT

I left the web page open over night and the upgrade completed after starting at 6AM. Anyone know why it waited until that time?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The upgrade was started by a timer job that ran at 6AM. 
The upgrade can be forced manually through PowerShell:

```
Upgrade-SPSite <http://site> -VersionUpgrade -Unthrottled
```